# TensorFlow 2.0 Cast string to float is not supported

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to follow along the Tensorflow Load CSV data tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv with my own data but I keep hitting a road block when it comes to packing the numeric data columns and then iterating through them. My code and traceback are below. Interesting thing is that it does not through the error when I call the Pack class and actually cast the columns to float32. The error is thrown when I try to display the result by iteration.

Thoughts?

Code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import functools

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os

fibro_path = "/Users/rdelemos/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/NASH/raw.csv"

batch_size = 32
selected_columns = ['age', 'sex', 'weight_kg', 'height_cm', 'bmi_calc', 'dm', 'fibro_cap', 'fibro_kpa', 'fib4',
                    'fib4_calc',
                    'fib4_comb', 'nfs_score', 'status']

numeric_columns = ['age', 'weight_kg', 'height_cm', 'bmi_calc', 'fibro_cap', 'fibro_kpa', 'fib4', 'fib4_calc',
                   'fib4_comb', 'nfs_score']

dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    fibro_path,
    batch_size,
    na_value="?",
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=True,
    select_columns=selected_columns,
    label_name='status'
)


def show_batch(dataset):
    for batch, label in dataset.take(1):
        for key, value in batch.items():
            print("{:20s}: {}".format(key, value.numpy()))


class PackNumericFeatures(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names

    def __call__(self, features, labels):
        numeric_features = [features.pop(name) for name in self.names]
        numeric_features = [tf.cast(feat, tf.float32) for feat in numeric_features]
        numeric_features = tf.stack(numeric_features, axis=-1)
        features['numeric'] = numeric_features

        return features, labels


packed_data = dataset.map(PackNumericFeatures(numeric_columns))

print("/////////////////////////////////////////////////////")

show_batch(packed_data)
```

Traceback:

```
2020-03-24 13:40:48.458261: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1599] OP_REQUIRES failed at cast_op.cc:123 : Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
2020-03-24 13:40:48.458288: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:642] Executor failed to create kernel. Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node Cast_4}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rdelemos/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/NASH/nash_ml.py", line 57, in <module>
    show_batch(packed_data)
  File "/Users/rdelemos/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/NASH/nash_ml.py", line 35, in show_batch
    for batch, label in dataset.take(1):
  File "/Users/rdelemos/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 332, in __iter__
    return iterator_ops.IteratorV2(self)
  File "/Users/rdelemos/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 593, in __init__
    self._create_iterator(dataset)
  File "/Users/rdelemos/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 611, in _create_iterator
    gen_dataset_ops.make_iterator(ds_variant, self._iterator_resource)
  File "/Users/rdelemos/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2929, in make_iterator
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node Cast_4}}]] [Op:MakeIterator]
```